# What's the evaluated value of <string> in if(<string>) in CMake?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

My hello.txt

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)

set(VAR ON)

# VAR will be treated as a string
if("VAR")
  message(TRUE)
else()
  message(FALSE)
endif()

# output prints FALSE
```

From policy CMP0054:

> To prevent ambiguity, potential variable or keyword names can be specified in a Quoted Argument or a Bracket Argument. A quoted or bracketed variable or keyword will be interpreted as a string and not dereferenced or interpreted. See policy CMP0054.

CMake documentation doesn't mention `if(<string>)`:

> `if(<variable|string>)`
>
> True if given a variable that is defined to a value that is not a false constant. False otherwise. (Note macro arguments are not variables.)

Why does a non-empty string evaluate as `FALSE`?

Comment: it seems like, in the documentation, `False otherwise` gives the answer? The behavior of treating the non-empty string as false is weird.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking in the right place in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#condition-syntax):

> `if(<variable|string>)`
>
> True if given a variable that is defined to a value that is not a false constant. False otherwise. (Note macro arguments are not variables.)

However, the documentation is not complete, as the `<string>` case is not explicitly mentioned. The behavior for CMake if-statements simply containing a string is *different* than what is described here for variables. The documentation for strings should read:

> True if given a string that does matches a true constant (`1`, `ON`, `YES`, `TRUE`, `Y`, or a non-zero number). False otherwise.

In other words, any string that doesn't match one of these CMake true constants will evaluate to False. As you already pointed out, the string `"VAR"`:

```
if ("VAR")
  message(TRUE)
else()
  message(FALSE)
endif()
```

prints `FALSE`. However, a true constant as a string (let's say `"y"`):

```
if ("y")
  message(TRUE)
else()
  message(FALSE)
endif()
```

prints `TRUE`.

This logic is verifiable in the CMake [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/417c533010e067ea78634e6ba50a1d2568949ad2/Source/cmConditionEvaluator.cxx#L213) in a function called `GetBooleanValue()`:

```
bool cmConditionEvaluator::GetBooleanValue(
  cmExpandedCommandArgument& arg) const
{
  // Check basic constants.
  if (arg == "0") {
    return false;
  }
  if (arg == "1") {
    return true;
  }

  // Check named constants.
  if (cmIsOn(arg.GetValue())) {
    return true;
  }
  if (cmIsOff(arg.GetValue())) {
    return false;
  }

  // Check for numbers.
  if (!arg.empty()) {
    char* end;
    double d = strtod(arg.c_str(), &end);
    if (*end == '\0') {
      // The whole string is a number.  Use C conversion to bool.
      return static_cast<bool>(d);
    }
  }

  // Check definition.
  const char* def = this->GetDefinitionIfUnquoted(arg);
  return !cmIsOff(def);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The source code is crystal clear! I also have a post on my blog https://guihao-liang.github.io/2020-01-04-cmake-101/, where I didn't read the source code but had a guess for the internal logic to evaluate conditions. I will update mine with your answer!